# can't install java on ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: java, ubuntu

i try to install java using

```
sudo apt install openjdk-17-jre-headless
```

and it give me this

```
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these. The following packages have unmet dependencies: jdk-17 : Depends: libc6-i386 but it is not going to be installed Depends: libc6-x32 but it is not going to be installed openjdk-17-jre-headless : Depends: ca-certificates-java (>= 20190405~) but it is not going to be installed Depends: java-common (>= 0.28) but it is not going to be installed N: Ignoring file 'openvpn3.listclear' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Have you tried?  apt --fix-broken install

Comment: This should not happen in normal usage. You must have done something to break it earlier …